# Get all column names (alias name) of resultant table of a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Consider the following stored procedure for fetching some data

```
SELECT 
    MatType_Id as 'ID', MatType_Code as 'Code', MatType_Name as 'Name',          
    Status_Id as 'Sid', 
    CASE 
        WHEN Status_Id = 1 THEN 'Active' 
        ELSE 'In Active' 
    END AS Status         
FROM 
    MM.MM_MATTYPE
```

I want to get all column 'alias' names in above stored procedure which are `ID`, `Code`, `Name`, `Sid` and `status` through a query.

I tried with the following query

```
select referenced_minor_name    
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('Sp_Name','object')
```

But its returning only actual column names `MatType_Id`, `MatType_Code`, `MatType_Name`, `Status_Id` and its not returning the last column `status`

Please someone help me to get all column alias names of a stored procedure in SQL Server.

Comment: Duplicate: [Retrieve column definition for stored procedure result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368864/retrieve-column-definition-for-stored-procedure-result-set)

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574773/retrieve-column-names-and-types-of-a-stored-procedure Hope it helps.

Comment: @RossPresser your solution not giving the extra column 'status' adding using case in my sp..

Comment: @john OpenQuery also not returning that extra column 'status' in my sp!  someone help me please..