# In SQL Server 2012, how do I get the column name and data type from a view, function, or stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am able to obtain column names and data types from a database table with:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'xxx'
```

How can I get the column name and data type from a view, function, or stored procedure?  I imagine I'd have to obtain them using the results of each but I'm unsure.

Thanks for the help

Comment: View columns are found in information_schema.columns too.

Comment: For an SP see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574773/retrieve-column-names-and-types-of-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Columns for *view:***

```
SELECT * FROM sys.columns c where c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('<schema>.<view name>')
```

**Columns for *table valued function*:**

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINE_COLUMNS rc WHERE rc.TABLE_NAME = '<udf name>'
```

**Columns for *stored procedure***

For SQL server 2012 and later:

```
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object
(
  OBJECT_ID('<shcema>.<sp name>'), 
  NULL
);
```

Taken from [Retrieve column names and types of a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574773/retrieve-column-names-and-types-of-a-stored-procedure). Read answers there for possible ways to do this (for example with pre 2012).