# Return All Column Names from Variable-Sized Result Set of Executed Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to return a column name list for a stored procedure with variable columns?

I have tried the following to no success. I can get it to work for the SPs with constant columns, *but not ones where the columns selected changes depending on the parameters*. The query returns null. Have I missed something or is it not possible?

```
**SELECT** name, column_ordinal **FROM** sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(  
N'EXEC dbo.SP_Name
@param, 
@param1, 
@param2, 
@param3, 
@param4, 
@param5, 
@param6;',  

N'@param varchar(max) = NULL, 
@param1 int = ''1234'', 
@param2 varchar(50) = ''tester_name'', 
@param3 varchar(120) = ''%'', 
@param4 varchar(20) = ''E'', 
@param5 varchar(20) = ''TEST'', 
@param6 tinyint = ''1'''
, 0);
```

Comment: what platform are you using?

Comment: I don't think it can be done, actually. This is old, but I think still applicable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574773/retrieve-column-names-and-types-of-a-stored-procedure Have a look at the comments under Aaron's answer.

Comment: @EricBrandt -- it is platform dependent.  For example, in SQL server you can use a function called `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object` in some versions.  There are similar "tools" in db2 and oracle -- the the only way to answer this question is to know the back end and the front end the user is using -- that is how I will be able to give the best answer.

Comment: @Hogan, the question is (and has been since the OP put it up) tagged as `SQL Server`, and the OP's example uses `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`. Both that and `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object` have issues with temp tables and dynamic SQL.

Comment: @EricBrandt -- and still my question remains the same.  For example in C# this is an easy problem to solve -- I have four lines of C# code that will load all columns into a dynamic.  Similarly Python can do such things -- what I would recommend to this new programmer depends on these details.